# Is there a tool to manage and monitor public cloud (AWS Azure, GCP) accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

We have 4 AWS accounts under one organization, 3 separate Azure accounts and 1 GCP account. Is there a tool we can use to manage and monitor all these public cloud accounts? We want to manage and monitor cost, resource usage and access. This could be a free or paid tool.

Thanks

Comment: where do you want to monitor all this? for example, are you willing to create a Grafana server, or are you asking to use StackDriver and put in there all the accounts?

Comment: Hello Cristian - Is it possible to  put in there all the accounts with StackDriver?

Answer (score 2):

You can ingest all that data in Stackdriver and monitor from one location.

Google recommends a Stackdriver partner service, Blue Medora BlindPlane, for collecting data from non GCP environments.

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/blue-medora

You can signup for the service in the Google Cloud Platform Marketplace at https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bluemedora/bindplane.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stackdriver Monitoring tool which supports integration of both AWS and GCP project. You can find more details along with the guidance at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/guide).